# How to change the Bgcolor of another element onclick using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have created a check box within a div and I want to make it so that when the check box is checked the div changes it's background colour with a fade. any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way:

```
if (numCorrect == 0) {
    score.append("You are stoopid");
} else if (numCorrect == 1) {
    score.append("You are pretty dumb");
} else if (numCorrect == 2) {
 ...
```

Another possibility would be to use an array of responses indexed by numCorrect.

```
var sayings = [ "You are stoopid", "You are pretty dumb", ... ];

score.append(sayings[numCorrect]);
```

Comment: Presumably in the `displayScore` function.